# Creating Web App timeout Insights for asp.net applications

Tags: asp.net, azure

We have a request to create insights as follows for timeouts from asp.net web applications (not core) hosted on Azure App Service

> Date
>
> Time (by at least hour)
>
> API endpoint

Ideally, this would also include a way to distinguish by:

> Default API endpoint
>
> API endpoint using filter

This is the first time I work on such a task. What is the best way to go about this? I was looking at [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/devops) but I noticed to get started it said something about iiservers. I don't think I have access to the server, can I still generate timeouts somehow by just hitting the web app URL?

I was also looking at [this](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Power-BI) article, and I think a PowerBI report would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Using Power BI for trend analysis of a small thing like request timeout for an API app would be cost inefficient.

Instead of that you can create App insight Dashboard using KQL query and pin in to a Dashboard.
[Please refer this MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/app-insights-metrics)

And We can choose -send request time `(browserTimings/sendDuration)` KQL query for it.

Comment: Can you emphasize on this part: `-send request time (browserTimings/sendDuration)`

Comment: Can you emphasize on this part: `-send request time (browserTimings/sendDuration)`